# Application not Result when user back from fragment?

Tags: android, transactions, fragment

I am working on android application .There are 4 tab on Home screen . there are multiple fragment under each tab.I am moving from fragment to second fragment and back on first fragment . when i again moves on second fragment . it does not show any data which i am fetching from web service.It is showing on progress dialog.what may reasons .

I am switching fragment like this.

```
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

            FragmentName llf = new FragmentName();

            ft.replace(R.id.container_framelayout, llf);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
```

Comment: How do you switch fragments?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's related to your problem but when you create a fragment from the same class multiple times, you shouldn't do 
    FragmentName llf = new FragmentName();

You should do something like that :

```
FragmentName llf = FragmentName.newInstance();
```

And in FragmentName.class :

```
public static FragmentName newInstance(){
    return new FragmentName();
}
```

This way, a new Fragment will be made and you won't have any duplicated or "shared" fragment. More information are available here : [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)